# Unwanted evaluation of RHS of association in FilterRules

Tags: options, associations

[`FilterRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilterRules.html) is a handy function that works on associations, however it does not respect delayed association-values. `RuleDelayed` is [allowed in associations](http://wolfram.com/xid/0bim351e-9eeopb), and they are not evaluated prematurely. Neither are delayed rules when a rule-list is supplied. I wonder what `FilterRules` does to an `Association` instead of simply applying `Normal` to it in the first place (which it can freely do, as the result is always a list and not an association). Do you think this is a bug? Or is there a deeper reason I failed to discover?

```
ClearAll[a, b];
FilterRules[{a :> Print["Evaluated"], b -> 1}, a]
(* {a :> Print["Evaluated"]} *)

FilterRules[Normal[<|a :> Print["Evaluated"], b -> 1|>], a]
(* {a :> Print["Evaluated"]} *)

FilterRules[<|a :> Print["Evaluated"], b -> 1|>, a]
(* During evaluation of In[63]:= Evaluated *)
(* {a -> Null} *)
```

Comment: Fortunately something designed for associations, works well: `KeyTake[<|a :> Print["Evaluated"]|>, a]`

Comment: @Kuba, that's true, but unfortunately `KeyTake` can not handle a pattern as a second argument correctly, e.g. `a|c`. By "correctly" I mean "how I would expect". Which also goes for the behaviour of the association iside `FilterRules`: "unexpected by me".

Comment: Submitted to TechSupport.